# File won't save output to file, and prints out a string oddly C++ Linux

Tags: c++, file-io, user-input

I'm trying to make a password code, the user enters a password, then it will save the password to a file in /tmp/ and then it will output the password (For me so I can find bugs). I have included the "string" library, and I set the password type to string, but when I output it, it outputs like this:

```
0x7fffb55baac0password // <-- thats the password I entered
```

It will output hex (I think), then the password I entered, and it won't save it to the file in /tmp/ I want it to (Or any file in /tmp/).
Here's the source code: http://codepad.org/3aamAv7R
Thank you for all the help you guys have given me so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ifstream password_read ("/tmp/qT9Cp0XPKZ.txt");
cout<< password_read;
password_read.close();
```

password_read is of type ifstream, so what you're going to get is either junk or its memory address. In order to display what is INSIDE password_read you need to have a variable hold said information.

```
 const int BUFFER = 1204; //maximum size of password(might be a large password)
 getline(password_read,Data,BUFFER); //if the password happens to contain whitespaces
 cout << Data;
```

also:

```
ofstream password ("/tmp/qT9Cp0XPKZ.txt");
password.open("/tmp/qT9Cp0XPKZ.txt");
```

the constructor of ofstream will open the file for you, so the following line afterwards is ambiguous.